# How do I get the profile picture having a user id from the friends picker?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the friends picker and obtain the selected user id. 
It's something like this :

```
AaLO4uyQLCrltBKryBnaTppP1ThNTREseQYV796H5JyPviztByQkST7Z362i7YIEYi2ZGcvX4shtFnXR0dd0g0yFwwRLt6SFTasdqNB19UtcvA
```

Then, I'm trying to obtain the user's public information and it's profile picture, but both requests return :

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: AaLO4uyQLCrltBKryBnaTppP1ThNTREseQYV796H5JyPviztByQkST7Z362i7YIEYi2ZGcvX4shtFnXR0dd0g0yFwwRLt6SFTasdqNB19UtcvA", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 803
}
}
```

I tested both in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=AaLO4uyQLCrltBKryBnaTppP1ThNTREseQYV796H5JyPviztByQkST7Z362i7YIEYi2ZGcvX4shtFnXR0dd0g0yFwwRLt6SFTasdqNB19UtcvA%2Fpicture%3Fredirect%3Dfalse&version=v2.1)

and the [url in the browser](http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/AaLO4uyQLCrltBKryBnaTppP1ThNTREseQYV796H5JyPviztByQkST7Z362i7YIEYi2ZGcvX4shtFnXR0dd0g0yFwwRLt6SFTasdqNB19UtcvA/picture?type=large)

Simply it does not work.
Is there a difference between the user id returned by the friends picker fragment, and the facebook id? I'm asking this because the id returned by the /me query is much shorter :

```
"id": "777840545588528"
```

Can anyone help me? What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Cristina, have you properly created HashKeys and app Id for Facebook developer acoount?

Answer (score 0):

you can get your friend's basic details like name,profile picture url etc.. by making a API call to  https:// graph.facebook.com /v2.1/me/taggable_friends.......And if you want to get your facebook friends I'd's you need to make a API call to . https:// graph.facebook.com /v2.1/me/friends which will return the user's friends I'd's using which you can make calls to API like this to fetch the details of your friends https:// graph.facebook.com /v2.1/user-id(of your friend which you got in earlier API call).....hope this helps